# Uniform Continuity of $\frac{x^3}{1+x^2}$ in R

Tags: real-analysis

Is the function $$\frac {x^3}{1 + x^2}$$ Uniformly continuous in R?

What I tried was this:
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = \lvert {x - \frac{x}{1 + x^2} - y + \frac{y}{1+y^2}}\rvert $$
$$ = |x-y|\cdot|\frac{x^2 + xy + y^2 + x^2y^2}{(1+x^2)\cdot(1+y^2)}|$$
I could not go further.

Comment: Domain of the function? Have you shown uniform continuity of any functions before? Although not completely true, the derivative being unbounded often implies the lack of uniform continuity , so you can study the derivative of the function. If the derivative is bounded we can think of the mean value theorem. (If my hints are helpful, kindly add any attempts you make into the question post, this will count for context. Or you can answer my questions, and then I will request you to put the answers into the question post).

Comment: Hint
: It is $x-\frac x {1+x^{2}}$ and the second term tends to $0$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: The domain is R

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with your calculation:
$$
\left| \frac{x^2 + xy + y^2 + x^2y^2}{(1+x^2)\cdot(1+y^2)} \right|
\le \frac{x^2 + y^2 + x^2y^2}{(1+x^2)\cdot(1+y^2)} + \frac{|xy|}{(1+x^2)\cdot(1+y^2)} \, .
$$
The first term is
$$
 \le \frac{1+x^2 + y^2 + x^2y^2}{(1+x^2)\cdot(1+y^2)} = 1 \, ,
$$
and the second term is
$$
 = \frac{|x|}{1+x^2} \cdot \frac{|y|}{1+y^2} \le \frac 12 \cdot \frac 12 \, ,
$$
using the inequality between geometric and arithmetic mean. It follows that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \le \frac 54 \cdot |x-y|
$$
so that the function is Lipschitz continuous, and in particular uniformly continuous.

Another approach (as mentioned in the comments) would be to compute
$$
f'(x) = \frac{x^2 (x^2 + 3)}{(1 + x^2)^2}
$$
and show that it is bounded (which follows e.g. from the fact that numerator and denominator have the same degree).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Mr Martin R

Comment: There is a shorter answer using my comment above. This fiunction is a difference of two uniformly continuous functions.